# Count Amount of Colored Squares in Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sw31uokt/

Here is some of the relevant code for the incrementValue function I set up to count overall clicks within the canvas element.

What I would like to do is be able to display a count of each color, so "you have placed 14 red pixels, 3 blue pixels, 4 black pixels'.

```
function incrementValue()
{
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

$(c_canvas).click(function(evt) {

var pos = getNearestSquare(getMousePos(c_canvas, evt));
if (pos != null) {
    context.fillStyle=(currentColor);
    context.fillRect(pos.x,pos.y,19,19);
    incrementValue(); 

}
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but couldn't you just keep a 2 dimensional array representing your currently applied colors and then count the colors in that array?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. What I'm trying to do is figure out how to populate the array using the color hex value as the key (as defined in the palette array), on each click.

Comment: Use the index of the color in palettes[]. Eg gridColors[pos.x,pos.y]=0. 0 would mean #333333, 1 would mean #0000FF, and so on. Then count the number of 1's and that tells you how many #0000FF's you have on the grid. Cheers!

Comment: OK, that makes sense... but how do I populate the 2nd column? How do I register a square as being index [1] or [2] or whatever?

Comment: Like this: var myPalette = ["333333","0000FF", "A0522D", "46ad42", "808080", "FFC0CB", "d73952",  "ffe2a8", "ffff7d", "ffffff"]; and then gridColors[pos.x,pos.y]=myPalette.indexOf(currentColor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what MarkE said above ...

In the outer scope, add two new vars :

```
var palette = ["333333", "0000ff", "a0522d", "46ad42", "808080", "ffc0cb", "d73952", "ffe2a8", "ffff7d", "ffffff"];//as originally defined in the .spectrum() call.

var gridModel = [];//Eventually a sparse array of sparse arrays, representing colored grid squares. Uncolored grid squares remain undefined.
```

And two new functions, in the same scope :

```
function updateGridModel(pos, color) {
    var x = (pos.x - 0.5) / 20;
    var y = (pos.y - 0.5) / 20;
    color = color.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    if (!gridModel[x]) {
        gridModel[x] = [];
    }
    gridModel[x][y] = palette.indexOf(color);
}

function paletteTally() {
    //initialise an array, same length as palettes, with zeros
    var arr = palette.map(function () {
        return 0;
    });
    for (var x = 0; x < gridModel.length; x++) {
        if (gridModel[x]) {
            for (var y = 0; y < gridModel[x].length; y++) {
                if (gridModel[x][y] !== undefined) {
                    arr[gridModel[x][y]] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Modify the canvas's click handler to keep the gridModel up to date :

```
$(c_canvas).click(function (evt) {
    var pos = getNearestSquare(getMousePos(c_canvas, evt));
    if (pos != null) {
        context.fillStyle = currentColor;
        context.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 19, 19);
        incrementValue();
        updateGridModel(pos, currentColor); //keep the gridModel up to date.
    }
});
```

Modify `printColor()` as follows :

```
function printColor(color) {
    currentColor = color.toHexString();
    $(".label").text(currentColor);
}
```

Modify the `.spectrum()` options and add an initialising call to `printColor()` as follows :

```
$("#showPaletteOnly").spectrum({
    color: palette[0],
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    showPalette: true,
    hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
    change: printColor,
    palette: [palette] //<<<< palette is now defined as an outer var
});

printColor( $("#showPaletteOnly").spectrum('get') );//initialize currentcolor and $(".label").text(...) .
```

Now `paletteTally()` will return an array congruent with `palette` containing counts of each color.

---

**EDIT 1**

Original code above was untested but is now debugged and includes improved `spectrum` options. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/658mxaqm/)**.